# wifi problems with lenovo g580 and ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, wireless, lenovo

I just bought a Lenovo G580 laptop, and installed Ubuntu 12.10 on it, everything works fine except for the WiFi connection, it connects fine but keeps dropping every few seconds and even when connected its extremely slow and Ubuntu will take a while to find the network to begin with.

The connection is working fine on windows, what is the problem?

The wirelss adapter is:

> Broadcom 4313

specific model:

> BCM4313HMGB BGN

thanks

Comment: Tell us details about your wifi adapter! You can find out with typing `sudo lshw -C network` on the command line. Please edit your question to show us that output.

Comment: @guntbert - main answer updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i followed the these instructions:

> > STA - No Internet access
>
> If you do not have any other means of Internet access on your
>   computer, you can install the bcmwl-kernel-source package from the
>   restricted folder under ../pool/restricted/b/bcmwl on the Ubuntu
>   install media.
>
> Note: The bcmwl-kernel-source package depends on the linux-headers
>   packages so you may need to first retrieve the appropriate package(s)
>   from the online repositories. A running LiveCD/LiveUSB environment has
>   these packages (allowing the wireless to work), but an installed
>   system may not. Make sure you have the linux-headers package that
>   matches your current kernel version, plus the appropriate generic
>   header packages so that they are automatically updated on a kernel
>   upgrade. To find out your current kernel use the command:
>
> uname -r
>
> To find what linux-headers packages you have installed use the
>   command:
>
> dpkg -l | grep headers
>
> Systems installed from CDROM can add the install CD as a package
>   source and install bcmwl-kernel-source using apt-get as above.
>   However, if you want to do it manually then the instructions are as
>   follows:
>
> Navigate the install media and install the packages listed below by
>   double clicking OR install the packages consecutively from a Terminal
>   (in the commands below the install media is mounted at /cdrom, but
>   yours maybe different):
>
> ```
> ../pool/main/d/dkms
>
> cd /cdrom/pool/main/d/dkms
> sudo dpkg -i dkms*
>
> ../pool/main/p/patch
>
> cd /cdrom/pool/main/p/patch
> sudo dpkg -i patch*
>
> ../pool/main/f/fakeroot
>
> cd /cdrom/pool/main/f/fakeroot
> sudo dpkg -i fakeroot*
>
> ../pool/restricted/b/bcmwl
>
> cd /cdrom/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl
> sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source*
> ```

taken from the official ubuntu help page:

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#STA_-_No_Internet_access

and after a restart wifi was working fine.