# Cant access the internet

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I am new user of Ubuntu. Almost everything is working fine, but I can't access the internet. I am connected to my home wifi, but can't access internet. Wifi is working fine on Windows 8 and cable connection is OK too. The laptop is a Lenovo G580 and wireless adapter is Broadcom BCM4313. I didn't install any drivers but in system info I can see I am using 3rd party drivers. How can I get the internet to work?

Answer (score 0):

I Recommend you try connecting your laptop though lan first, Then see if there are any additional drivers to install.

Also I Have Found this:

```
    STA - No Internet access

If you do not have any other means of Internet access on your computer, you can install the bcmwl-kernel-source package from the restricted folder under ../pool/restricted/b/bcmwl on the Ubuntu install media.

Note: The bcmwl-kernel-source package depends on the linux-headers packages so you may need to first retrieve the appropriate package(s) from the online repositories. A running LiveCD/LiveUSB environment has these packages (allowing the wireless to work), but an installed system may not. Make sure you have the linux-headers package that matches your current kernel version, plus the appropriate generic header packages so that they are automatically updated on a kernel upgrade. To find out your current kernel use the command:

uname -r

To find what linux-headers packages you have installed use the command:

dpkg -l | grep headers

Systems installed from CDROM can add the install CD as a package source and install bcmwl-kernel-source using apt-get as above. However, if you want to do it manually then the instructions are as follows:

Navigate the install media and install the packages listed below by double clicking OR install the packages consecutively from a Terminal (in the commands below the install media is mounted at /cdrom, but yours maybe different):

../pool/main/d/dkms

cd /cdrom/pool/main/d/dkms
sudo dpkg -i dkms*

../pool/main/p/patch

cd /cdrom/pool/main/p/patch
sudo dpkg -i patch*

../pool/main/f/fakeroot

cd /cdrom/pool/main/f/fakeroot
sudo dpkg -i fakeroot*

../pool/restricted/b/bcmwl

cd /cdrom/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source*
```

From This Thread: [wifi problems with lenovo g580 and ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240766/wifi-problems-with-lenovo-g580-and-ubuntu-12-10)

For this, You Must Connect using lan.

Comment: I have tried to connect via LAN and download all updates...after restart nothing changed, os i have tried to install these package from install CD, but after restart i still cant connect to internet via Wi-fi